# Multiple Directives on an Element NOT WORKING

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an input element with two directives(attribute) in it. it adds an **error** class if the input is not valid.

```
<input required alpha type="text" name="firstName" ng-model="newUser.firstName" class="form-control" maxlength="30" placeholder="First Name" />
```

and these are my directives

```
// SHOWS AN ERROR IF THE INPUT IS EMPTY
directives.required = function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.on('keyup', function(event) {
                if(elem.val().trim() == '') {
                    elem.prop('title', 'This input is required!');
                    elem.addClass('error');
                } else {
                    elem.prop('title', '');
                    elem.removeClass('error');
                }
            })
        }
    }   
};

// SHOWS AN ERROR IF THE INPUT CONTAINS NON ALPHA CHARACTERS
directives.alpha = function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var regexp = /^[A-Za-z ñÑ]+$/;
            var char;
            elem.on('keyup', function(event) {
                if(!regexp.test(elem.val())) {
                    elem.prop('title', 'This input can contain letters only!');
                    elem.addClass('error');
                } else {
                    elem.prop('title', '');
                    elem.removeClass('error');
                }
            })
        }
    }   
};
```

But it didnt do what i expect. only one directive is working! When I tried to remove the attribute **alpha** , **required** now works! Can someone tell me why it works like this?

Comment: Have you tried changing "error" class name for example in alpha directive? it's possible alpha directive is overwriting class "error" of required directive or viceversa

Comment: I don't know why it is not working (I didn't look into it), but you are reinventing the wheel here. Take a better look at the built-in input directive and the built-in ngModelController/formController.

Comment: Aren't the directives' `keyup` handlers going to clobber each other in the case of one passing validation and one failing?

Comment: @Ragnar i tried changing it to xrequired and xalpha, but still behaves the same way.

Comment: @ExpertSystem are referring to ng-pattern, ng-minlength, etc.? I tried that weeks ago and cant get it to worked what I want so eneded up with this solution. Now I dont have the time so study it becuase Im on emergency right now hahahha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They doesn't work together because they overwrite each other changes. I added extra condition to avoid this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="plunker">
        <div  ng-controller="MainCtrl">
            <input required="" alpha="" type="text" name="firstName" ng-model="newUser.firstName" class="form-control" maxlength="30" placeholder="First Name" />
        </div>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
            app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

            }]).directive('required', function() {
                return {
                    restrict: 'A',
                    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
                        elem.on('keyup', function(event) {
                            var title = 'This input is required!';
                            if(elem.val().trim() == '') {
                                elem.prop('title', 'This input is required!');
                                elem.addClass('error');
                            } else if (elem.prop('title') == title) {
                                elem.prop('title', '');
                                elem.removeClass('error');
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }   
            }).directive('alpha', function() {
                return {
                    restrict: 'A',
                    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
                        var regexp = /^[A-Za-z]*$/;
                        var char;
                        elem.on('keyup', function(event) {
                            var title = 'This input can contain letters only!';
                            if(!regexp.test(elem.val())) {
                                elem.prop('title', title);
                                elem.addClass('error');
                            } else if (elem.prop('title') == title) {
                                elem.prop('title', '');
                                elem.removeClass('error');
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }   
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want can be achieved with built-in directives and controller-functionality:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First name" ng-model="someProp"
        ng-pattern="/^[A-Za-z ñÑ]*$/" ng-required="true"
        title="{{form1.firstName.$error.pattern?'Should only contain letters':
                 form1.firstName.$error.required?'This field is required':''}}" />

/* CSS */
input.ng-invalid-pattern,
input.ng-invalid-required {
    /* Put the styles for your .error class here */
}
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/3o8g8hbs/)**.

Comment: ah yeah. i tried something like that before, but I also want to get rid of so many angular conditions in an element.

Comment: @AlexCoroza: I assume you refer to the `title` expression (because other than that the conditions are the same as in your example). For that you can either create a directive to just set the title based on the validity (you don't need to set error classes, since that is taken care of for you.) or (instead of changing the `title`) it is usually better to porvide some error message (take a look at ngMessages for that as well).